# DateTime.Min JSON Serialisation Incorrect

Tags: javascript, c#

I am trying to figure this strange behaviour on a client machine (IE10)

When we create a new javascript Object, the ajax response from the server is `\/Date(-62135596800000)\/`.

I format the JSON Date in the following way:

`var date  = new moment(parseInt(response.substr(6)));`

On the Client machine this Date Object returns the following Date Format `0000-12-31`.

When I try to validate the Date on the Server I get the response is an error saying that this is not a valid date.

My validation is Fluent Validation and the Rule is

```
RuleFor(x=>x.LastUpdateDate).NotEmpty();
```

Can anyone point me in the correct direction to help solve this issue?

Comment: You're creating a date from the timestamp `-62135596800000`, a negative number. It's therefore giving you a date that's that many milliseconds *before* the beginning of the epoch. If I were you I'd fix the server so that it produced a less bizarre date format.

Comment: That is how JSON Serialiser in .NET serialises dates. The Project is too large currently to change the default one.

Comment: OK well whatever. If it's predictable then I guess it works. Anyway the root problem is that your timestamp actually is for a date in the year 0 CE.

Comment: But it actually isnt as easy as that. on most machines it shows as the .NET DateTime.Min of `0001-01-01` only on some machines is it 1 day before.

Comment: That's because different machines are in different time zones. A timestamp value is always interpreted as being relative to a fixed UTC reference time, but when you *look at* a JavaScript date, you get the date in local time (unless you use the UTC APIs available on the Date prototype). (added this as an answer)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your timestamp value is interpreted as being an offset from a fixed UTC reference point. However, when you do something like

```
alert(theDate)
```

you'll see the default rendition of the Date instance as it would appear *in the local time zone*. In other words, a computer in Hong Kong will show the same UTC date differently than a computer in London.

You can use

```
alert(theDate.toUTCString())
```

to see a UTC version of the date.

Comment: Thanks @Pointy that would make alot of sense in the terms of what is happening on the App.